# Overriding Rails Default Routing Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing an app where I need to override the default routing helpers for a model.  So if I have a model named Model, with the corresponding helper model_path() which generates "/model/[id]".  I'd like to override that helper to generate "/something/[model.name]".  I know I can do this in a view helper, but is there a way to override it at the routing level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `to_param` on your model. It's return value is going to be used in generated URLs as the id.

```
class Thing
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

The you can adapt your routes to scope your resource like so

```
scope "/something" do
  resources :things
end
```

Alternatively, you could also use sub-resources is applicable.

Finally you need to adapt your controller as `Thing.find(params[:id])` will not work obviously.

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @thing = Thing.where(:name => params[:id).first
  end
end
```

You probably want to make sure that the `name` of your `Thing` is unique as you will observe strange things if it is not.

To save the hassle from implementing all of this yourself, you might also be interested in [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) which gives you this and some additional behavior (e.g. for using  generated slugs)

Answer (score 0):

You need the scope in routes.rb

```
scope "/something" do
  resources :models
end
```

Comment: yeah, but I don't want the id in the path - won't adding that scope create a path like "/something/model/[model.id]"?  I need it to look like "/something/[model.name]" instead

Comment: hmm, that gets me pretty close - I'm still seeing the id in the url that is generated by model_path() though.  I'd like to be able to access model.name instead of it defaulting to model.id